# Why does this order of transformations fail?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I'm trying to transform $rect(t)$ but depending on the order I apply the transformations, I end up with different results.

I start with $rect(t)$ and the goal is to get to $rect\left(\frac{t}{2}-\frac{1}{3}\right)$

Real briefly (just in case), $rect(t) = 1, \left|t\right| < \frac{1}{2}$

(apologies in advance for my bad handwriting and drawing skills!)

**First Way (wrong):**

[image]

**Second Way (correct):**

[image]

The length of both rectangles matches for both ways. It's just the roots that have different positions.

What's the reason why a stretch-and-shift works, but not a shift-and-stretch? I feel like maybe in the first way, I'm getting the stretch wrong?

**Quick Fix:** The ending function in the second picture should have a leftmost root of $-1/3$, not $1/3$

Comment: Stretching along the $y$ axis corresponds to just dividing $t$ by $2$, not the whole $t-\frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: @Wojowu ah shoot, in that case I first need to shift by $1/3$ then, not $2/3$. That actually fixes everything, thanks! In college but transformations still confuse me every now and then!

Comment: I feel like such things may confuse everyone from time to time :)

Comment: The crux here is the order of composition of functions. It is not commutative. Thus  $(t-2/3)/2$ is not the same as $(t/2)-2/3$ which is want you wanted. In these kind of problems it is not always obvious which order to compose.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way that may be less confusing. You stated that $rect(t)=1$ for $|t|<1$, i.e. the limits of $rect$ being 1 are $\pm 1$. To get the limits of $rect\left ({t \over 2}-{1 \over 3}\right)$ being 1, just set $${t \over 2}-{1 \over 3}=\pm1$$ and solve for $t$.

Comment: Yeah that's the way I usually do it, but in a pinch on the test I feel graphically might sometimes be a slightly easier way than solving inequalities (depending on the function of course!)